# Not quite understand what does the i stand for in forEach function in my code

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am using this method to find the frequency of words, however i am a bit confused with the whole code.

Here is the code:

```js
function check(){
 var word = document.querySelector('textarea').value.split(" ");
   frequency ={};
   word.forEach(function(i){
      console.log(i)
      if(!frequency[i]){
         frequency[i] = 0;
      }
      frequency[i]+=1
   })
console.log(frequency)
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<button onclick = 'check()'>check</button>
```

I just wonder what does the `i` stand for and what does the `frequency[i]`.

Could someone explain to me a little bit because I think this code is not quite friendly for me, the beginner.

Comment: [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and try to `console.log(i)` you will see your "error"

Comment: That code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You need to declare `frequency`. I also would initialize it with `Object.create(null)`, not `{}` (or better yet, use a `Map`). You can also use a `for..of` loop rather than `forEach` which might be clearer. Re `frequency[i]`, see [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foreach iterates over array, and as paramter has function into which is passed as parameter actual element of array. So i in this function is actual element of 'word' array.

for object frequency is frequency[i] the i'th element. At start, this object is empty, so frequency[i] will be undefined, but in foreach loop you filling this object with some values so in next iterations there may by some values